Unable to Build Rust Program with jupiter-core Dependency for Swapping SOL to USDC
I started learning Solana very recently and right now I'm trying to perform a swap transaction to swap SOL to USDC.
I found out that there's a Jupiter DEX and I'm trying to use its library. But weirdly, when I add jupiter-core as my dependency, it fails to build. However, when I cloned that library and tried to compile it, it compiled perfectly fine.
What could be wrong?
here's related files and terminal output:
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "solana_learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
resolver = "2"

[dependencies]
jupiter-core = { git = "https://github.com/jup-ag/jupiter-amm-implementation" }

main.rs
fn main() {}


   Compiling spl-pod v0.1.0
   Compiling solana-client v1.16.15
   Compiling solana-runtime v1.16.15
   Compiling anchor-generate-cpi-crate v0.3.1 (https://github.com/jup-ag/anchor-gen.git?rev=26c04a10d20509f360ab176d003bea4c625b16f2#26c04a10)
   Compiling anchor-generate-cpi-interface v0.3.1 (https://github.com/jup-ag/anchor-gen.git?rev=26c04a10d20509f360ab176d003bea4c625b16f2#26c04a10)
   Compiling spl-tlv-account-resolution v0.4.0 (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library.git?rev=79a575fb7af56d26deeda94fef8f55bde7a90df3#79a575fb)
   Compiling spl-token v4.0.1
   Compiling spl-memo v4.0.1
   Compiling anchor-lang v0.28.0
   Compiling jupiter-amm-interface v0.3.3
error[E0659]: `solana_program` is ambiguous
 --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/error.rs:5:1
  |
5 | #[spl_program_error]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous name
  |
  = note: ambiguous because of a conflict between a name from a glob import and an outer scope during import or macro resolution
  = note: `solana_program` could refer to a crate passed with `--extern`
  = help: use `::solana_program` to refer to this crate unambiguously
note: `solana_program` could also refer to the crate imported here
 --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/error.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use spl_program_error::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: consider adding an explicit import of `solana_program` to disambiguate
  = help: or use `self::solana_program` to refer to this crate unambiguously
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `spl_program_error` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:28:54
   |
28 |             return Err(PodSliceError::BufferTooSmall.into());
   |                                                      ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:48:62
   |
48 |             .ok_or_else(|| PodSliceError::CalculationFailure.into())
   |                                                              ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:66:54
   |
66 |             return Err(PodSliceError::BufferTooSmall.into());
   |                                                      ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:103:47
    |
103 |             Err(PodSliceError::BufferTooSmall.into())
    |                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:116:50
    |
112 | fn max_len_for_type<T>(data_len: usize) -> Result<usize, ProgramError> {
    |                                            --------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
116 |         .ok_or(PodSliceError::CalculationFailure)?;
    |          ----------------------------------------^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<usize, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, PodSliceError>>`
    |          |
    |          this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, PodSliceError>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<usize, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, PodSliceError>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:121:47
    |
121 |             Err(PodSliceError::BufferTooSmall.into())
    |                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<PodSliceError>` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-pod-0.1.0/src/slice.rs:123:47
    |
123 |             Err(PodSliceError::BufferTooLarge.into())
    |                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<PodSliceError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `PodSliceError: Into<_>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `PodSliceError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0659.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `spl-pod` (lib) due to 8 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_sdk::account::Account: solana_sdk::account::ReadableAccount` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/jupiter-amm-interface-0.3.3/src/lib.rs:203:50
    |
203 |         let ui_account = UiAccount::encode(&key, &account, UiAccountEncoding::Base64, None, None);
    |                          -----------------       ^^^^^^^^ the trait `solana_sdk::account::ReadableAccount` is not implemented for `solana_sdk::account::Account`
    |                          |
    |                          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `solana_sdk::account::ReadableAccount`:
              Ref<'_, solana_sdk::account::Account>
              Ref<'_, solana_sdk::account::AccountSharedData>
              solana_sdk::account::Account
              solana_sdk::account::AccountSharedData
note: required by a bound in `UiAccount::encode`
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-account-decoder-1.16.15/src/lib.rs:82:22
    |
82  |     pub fn encode<T: ReadableAccount>(
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `UiAccount::encode`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/jupiter-amm-interface-0.3.3/src/lib.rs:203:44
    |
203 |         let ui_account = UiAccount::encode(&key, &account, UiAccountEncoding::Base64, None, None);
    |                          ----------------- ^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |                          |
    |                          arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-2.0.0/src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    |
96  | pub struct Pubkey(pub(crate) [u8; 32]);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-1.16.15/src/pubkey.rs:87:1
    |
87  | pub struct Pubkey(pub(crate) [u8; 32]);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: associated function defined here
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-account-decoder-1.16.15/src/lib.rs:82:12
    |
82  |     pub fn encode<T: ReadableAccount>(
    |            ^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_sdk::account::Account: solana_sdk::account::WritableAccount` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/jupiter-amm-interface-0.3.3/src/lib.rs:223:14
    |
223 |             .decode()
    |              ^^^^^^ the trait `solana_sdk::account::WritableAccount` is not implemented for `solana_sdk::account::Account`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `solana_sdk::account::WritableAccount`:
              solana_sdk::account::Account
              solana_sdk::account::AccountSharedData
note: required by a bound in `UiAccount::decode`
   --> /Users/eugene/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-account-decoder-1.16.15/src/lib.rs:141:22
    |
141 |     pub fn decode<T: WritableAccount>(&self) -> Option<T> {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `UiAccount::decode`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308.
error: could not compile `jupiter-amm-interface` (lib) due to 3 previous errors


I think the project needs to upgrade to a newer version of spl-program-error, since that was resolved in a later release
